# multiple linear regression vs polynomial regression models

Tags: r, regression

I am working on a marketing budget plan, i used both multiple linear regression and polynomial regression models. I am not sure if i can compare them based on rse and adjusted r squared, like choose a better model based on these two measures. If I can not, how should I find a better model ?

Comment: This needs more details. Multiple linear regression is a special case of polynomial regression, where the degree of the polynomial is 1, and there are many approaches to model selection.

Comment: Among the many approaches to model selection are: Adjusted R^2, AIC, BIC, Mallow's C_p, PRESS statistic, stepwise regression, Lasso, Best Subsets Regression, etc. This is by no means an exhaustive list. (Maximizing Adjusted R^2 is equivalent to minimizing RSE.)

Comment: Also, it depends what your goal is? Do you care only about prediction ? Then, cross-validation is the golden standard (see e.g. PRESS statistic which is equivalent to leave-one-out cross-validation). Do you care about the actual model, then look into one of the many approaches ... some of which I mentioned above.

Comment: Our goal is to come up with a advertising plan for next year,meaning how much money should we put toward each social media platform based on the sales revenue from each social media before. I did not use train set and test set, because this is unnecessary. From what i have is RSE and adjusted r squared, from the model output. Just don't know if i can compare the output from linear model to the output from polynomial model .

Comment: I'd steer clear of adjusted r^2 and RSE and choose one of the metrics like AIC that @passerby51 mentioned.  Consider the bias-variance tradeoff... the polynomial model will likely fit the observed data better but fail to generalize to new data due to overfitting.  Using RSE or adjusted r^2 could be misleading in this case.

Comment: @Gracetam, it seems that your main goal is revenue prediction. I would go with cross-validation. You can compare any two models on their prediction performance using cross-validation (perhaps the simplest approach is via the [PRESS statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRESS_statistic)). Otherwise, I suggest giving [Bayesian Information Criteria (BIC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) a shot for model selection.